# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer despite using int() function

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm getting type error for following line:

```
a, b = task_one(int(input("Enter number of your choosing: "), input("Enter second number: " )))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I don't understand why input is classified as a string when I enter integers and use int() function.

Comment: You're passing two strings as arguments to `int()`.  It's complaining about the second one, which is the optional `base` argument and must be an integer.  You can't convert multiple strings within one call to `int()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the better way when you are taking multiple inputs in single line.

```
a,b = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: I tried using split() in a slightly different way before but it didn't work. I tried your suggestion anyway but I got the same error as back then. It says I'm missing one required positional argument 'b'

Comment: You have to give both input in same line using space, for example "2 3" these will be your 2 inputs

Comment: I know but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: You can visit [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python/) for references.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you would like each of the inputs to be integers, therefore you need to convert each of them on their own -

```
a, b = task_one(int(input("Enter number of your choosing: ")), int(input("Enter second number: " )))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
input("Enter number of your choosing: "), input("Enter second number: " )
```

For example, input `1` and `2`, returns `('1', '2')`. It cannot be converted to `int`:

```
>>> input("Enter number of your choosing: "), input("Enter second number: " )
Enter number of your choosing: 1
Enter second number: 2
('1', '2')
```

---

If `task_one` is a function that takes two ints, you should write it this way:

```
a, b = task_one(int(input("Enter number of your choosing: ")), int(input("Enter second number: " ))))
```

Comment: It isn't a tuple, it's just two arguments to `int()`.